# How to validate email uniqueness with pydantic and fastapi

Tags: python, pymongo, fastapi, pydantic

i'm trying to validate input email from request body and i have build custom field validator at model.

here is code of RegisterModel:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, EmailStr, Field, field_validator
from repository.repository_user import UserRepository
from pprint import pprint 

class RegisterModel(BaseModel):
   name:str
   email:EmailStr 
   password:str = Field(..., min_length=7)

   @field_validator('email')
   @classmethod
   def email_must_unique(cls, v):
      repo = UserRepository()
      result = repo.find({'email': v})
      pprint(result)
      return result
```

the email_must_unique method will create new instace of UserRepository class and it will call the find method from UserRepository to find specific user based on email. actualy the email_must_unique method not finished yet to validate the email, it just get specific users, but i already facing an error.

here is code of UserRepository:

```py
from pymongo.database import Database
from fastapi import Depends
from config.db import db_conn

class UserRepository:
    def __init__(self, db: Database = Depends(db_conn)):
        self.repository = db.users   # users is mongo collection

    def find(self, filter: dict):
        result = self.repository.find_one(filter)
        return result
```

with this code i'm facing error like this:

```
    self.repository = db.users
                      ^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Depends' object has no attribute 'users'
```

i have no idea what What caused it.
can you give me the solution to solve this error or maybe alternative way to validate email uniqueness ?

Comment: I wouldn't do it inside the model's field validator. I think it's not a pydantic model's job. Just check the uniqueness in your endpoint function

Comment: `Depends` only gets evaluated when used in a controller's signature in FastAPI (and the hierarchy from that signature). You can't use `Depends` in a random method/function signature and expect it to get evaluated; you can however just call `db_conn()` directly; but - this is a business rule, so that should happen in your service layer, not in the pydantic layer. I'd keep it outside of the controller as well.

Comment: You don't need to use `Depends` in your `UserRepository` object. You can pass your `db_conn` directly. Also, in `Depends docs` we can see: `Declare a FastAPI dependency. It takes a single "dependable" callable (like a function). Don't call it directly, FastAPI will call it for you. Read more about it in the` [FastAPI docs for Dependencies](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by [@Chiheb Nexus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3926995/chiheb-nexus), Do not call the `Depends` function directly. Instead, use the [`Annotated` dependency](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/#share-annotated-dependencies) which is more graceful.

For example, the `config/db.py` file should look like this:

```py
# config/db.py
from typing import Annotated

from fastapi import Depends
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pymongo.database import Database


def get_db() -> Database:
    client = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
    return client.some_database


DbConn = Annotated[Database, Depends(get_db)]  # <-- this is the annotated depend
```

You can then use it like this:

```py
from config.db import DbConn


class UserRepository:
    def __init__(self, db: DbConn):  # <- FastAPI will call `DbConn`
        self.repository = db.users

    def find(self, filter: dict):
        result = self.repository.find_one(filter)
        return result
```

In addition, `db` in the `__init__` parameter is annotated via `DbConn` so IDE knows its type.

Validating the uniqueness of data is a task best left to the database rather than Pydantic. In other words, you should insert data and handle unique errors, `DuplicateKeyError` in pymongo.